# Java not iterating all the way through array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have 5 rectObj yet the loop is only continuing twice.

Here's my code:

```
public boolean bottomLeft() {
    boolean ret = false;
    Iterator<rectObj> rectItr = Main.rectAr.iterator();
    while (rectItr.hasNext() && ret == false) {
        rectObj e = rectItr.next();
        if (x > e.getX() && x < e.getX()+e.getWidth()
                && y+h > e.getY() && y+h < e.getX()+e.getHeight()) {
            ret = true;
        }else{
            if(rectItr.hasNext()) {
                rectItr.next();
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

rectObj rect1 = new rectObj(250,250,50,50);
    rectObj rect2 = new rectObj(0,440,500,50);
    rectObj rect3 = new rectObj(0,0,500,50);
    rectObj rect4 = new rectObj(400,200,50,50);
    rectObj rect5 = new rectObj(0,200,50,50);

    rectAr.add(rect1);
    rectAr.add(rect2);
    rectAr.add(rect3);
    rectAr.add(rect4);
    rectAr.add(rect5);
```

I want the loop to continue throughout all of the array unless it finds an object that it has collided with.

Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `rectItr.next()` a second time in the `else` part inside the loop. Try removing the else part of the if-else statement.

The else part is checking if `rectItr.hasNext()` and if it has, it is calling `rectItr.next()`. Then it returns to the top of the while loop which is doing the same thing again. Therefore, each loop, if the `if` test is false, then it calls `rectItr.next()` an extra time, and skips the next element in the array.

Comment: I removed the next statement and the collision was detected for another rectObj but removed for one that was working with the next satement

Comment: Ah, I removed the if statement completely and now it works great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

@Dermot is correct.

You can actually simplify and reformat the method as follows:

```
public boolean bottomLeft() {
    for (rectObj e : Main.rectAr) {
        if (x > e.getX() 
                && x < e.getX() + e.getWidth()
                && y + h > e.getY() 
                && y + h < e.getX() + e.getHeight()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

... and this reveals that there is ANOTHER bug in your method.  This line

```
      && y + h < e.getX() + e.getHeight()
```

... should be ...

```
      && y + h < e.getY() + e.getHeight()
```

... I think.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake!
However "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"

Comment: @StephenC I saw a very interesting talk/blog post a while back which had a specific note that when you have sections of code which are largely copied, but with small differences, there is overwhelmingly often a bug in one of the later copies just like this.